# How to make a keyboard shortcut to close dialog with Xcode/Interface Builder?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, keyboard-shortcuts

This seems awfully basic but here goes. If you are keyboard-oriented you get used to using Command-W to close windows all the time in OS X. I'd like to add that capability to the dialogs I am creating in Interface Builder for my program.  I can see how to add a keyboard equivalent to a button action but what if I don't have a button?

Should I add an invisible button and put the shortcut on that?  Seems clunky.  Surely there is just some method I can override but what I've tried so far isn't working.

Comment: It is also standard to assign ESC to the close of dialogs. :)

Comment: I seem to have gotten ESC for free. But Apple's own programs (e.g., System Preferences) respond to Command-W as well as ESC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an invisible button works just fine.

Comment: But is not necessary. I created a new project, ran it without doing anything to it, and was able to ⌘W its About window. If you're not able to do that, then you broke ⌘W and should fix it. Make sure the Close menu item is connected to First Responder, and not a specific window.

Comment: You're right: I had accidentally broken Command-W by mucking around with the menu.  The details of the bad thing I did are not interesting but I brought it back to its original state and everything works now without the need for magic invisible buttons.

Answer (score 10):

When you press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, it's the exact same as choosing `File -> Close` from the menu bar. What `Close` does is send a [`performClose:`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/performClose:) message to the first responder. That, in turn, will check if the receiver or if the receiver's delegate implements [`windowShouldClose:`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/windowShouldClose:), and the window will close if it returns `YES` (otherwise, it will call the `close` method).

So really, it depends on what type of dialog you've got here. If it's non-modal (essentially, if you can access the menu bar while it's running) and is an instance or subclass of `NSWindow`, then all you need to do is override the `windowShouldClose:` method in your dialog's delegate (or your dialog class, if you subclassed `NSWindow` or something) and make it return `YES`.

**However**, if the dialog is a modal dialog (you can't access the menu bar, switch windows, etc. while the dialog is running), then you can't do it this way. You *could* add an invisible button, but in all honesty, a modal dialog should not be closed by hitting `Command-W`, for that most certainly violates some Apple interface guideline out there. (Especially since, as Ande noted, it's standard practice to have <kbd>Esc</kbd> close/cancel a dialog.)

Comment: It is an instance of NSWindow. What you suggest makes sense but when I override windowShouldClose: in the delegate that method is not called when Command-W is pressed. I tried overriding performKeyEquivalent: but that doesn't get called either. Any key I press (except Command-Q which quits the whole application) just beeps.

Comment: That sounds like your dialog is modal—in other words, the rest of the interface is disabled while the dialog is running. In this case, you can't (and shouldn't) try to make Command-W close the dialog. You should instead add a "Cancel" button which would map to Esc and/or Command-Period. This is more in line with expected behavior and established interface guidelines.

Comment: No, it's modeless. I have a few dialogs, but to pick one specific example, the About dialog. Like in Xcode itself, the About box is modeless, and I'd like to be able to dismiss it with Command-W, as in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Is the dialog an `NSWindow`? Because by default the `File->Close` menu option is set to the `performClose:` action of the first responder, and already wired to `command-w`

If the dialog isn't a window simply make your dialog first responder and implement the `performClose:` action.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try this:

```
-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent{

    //If the key is X or x it just closes the window
    if ([theEvent.characters.uppercaseString isEqualToString:@"X"]) {
        [self.window performClose:self];
    }

}
```

or if you want to show a window you can instanciate and show it there instead of the performClose

Answer (score 0):

Jasper was right about the code part. For interface builder(storyboard), there is a quick fix:

1. In your storyboard, hit "CMD+Shift+L" to bring up the components lib, select File Menu Item.

[image]

2. Add the file menu item to the Application Scene's Main Menu Node. (Remove unwanted file menus)

[image]

Now you have a keyboard shortcut to close a window.